# Use of 'more' , 'less' in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am taking an SQL class in school.

There was a question:

> "Find the id and name of those students in the Statistics department who have less that a tenth the total credits of the student in the Statistics department with the most credits. List your result in ID order and do not print duplicates."

To answer it, I did the following:

Schemas:

- classroom(building, room number, capacity)
- department(dept name, building, budget)
- course(course id, title, dept name, credits)
- instructor(ID, name, dept name, salary)
- section(course id, sec id, semester, year, building, room number, time slot id)
- teaches(ID, course id, sec id, semester, year)
- student(ID, name, dept name, tot cred)
- takes(ID, course id, sec id, semester, year, grade)
- advisor(s ID, i ID)
- time slot(time slot id, day, start time, end time)
- prereq(course id, prereq id)

My Answer:

```
    select DISTINCT ID, name
    from student
    where DEPT_NAME = 'Statistics' and TOT_CRED < .1* 128;
```

In my answer I hardcoded the max credit hours 128, which gives the correct solution but would not certainly work all the time.One of the top students did it the following way:

```
select distinct tochar(less.id,'00009') as ID, less.name 
from student more, student less 
where less.totcred<more.totcred / 10 and more.deptname = 'Statistics' and less.deptname = 'Statistics' 
order by id;
```

I did not ask him anything because I was feeling shy.But can someone explain the use of 'less', and 'more' here?

Comment: they are aliases for the `student` table. This query is used to run a pairwise comparison on all rows of the table.

Comment: If that is the work of the top student, the professor must be pretty bad.  It is not even correct.

Comment: They are just table aliases that are required since the same table is joined twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am at the novice state but I do really want to learn it better.Can you recommend better book?They're using database system concepts by hank korth at my school.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please explain why it is not correct?

Comment: Gordon is absolutely right - if that is the best student's solution, that's bad news for the class. Have you, since, found the right way to solve this problem? I know that's not what you asked, so no one has offered a better solution than your best student found. Not sure if you needed one...

Comment: The answer from the top student is not correct because there is nothing in that answer that identifies the number of credits for the top student.

Comment: @mathguy I would appreciate a better solution offered by anyone on this thread.

Comment: @HagaDhorse Writing SQL to suit a requirement often involves breaking the requirement down into simpler steps and then building up the final solution step-by-step. In your case, I would start by finding out what the highest amount of credits was. Then I would use that value divided by 10 to compare to each student's number of credits. Why don't you give that a go, and if you get stuck, ask another question and explain what you've done so far and we'll help you out some more. Good luck! *{:-)

Comment: @HagaDhorse also, if you want to improve your SQL writing skills, you might want to read more of the other Oracle SQL questions and answers on this site (and also on other forums, such as AskTom, etc) and try out the solutions for yourself. Or even try answering questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`more` and `less` are table aliases. The solution selects from the STUDENTS table twice, a self-join, and the aliases are necessary to distinguish between the two instances. Aliases can be anything but `more` and `less` are more expressive than `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I see it now.We needed alias to compare.However, why are you saying they are expensive?Because they use more letters?

Comment: Read it again.  He didn't say expensive.